# Bootstrap4 layout problem - fill browser page height with contents

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

We should create the following layout panels:
[image: A complicated layout]

The #2 panel contains fewer or more lines, so its vertical size cannot be computed statically. The #3 and #4 should fill the remaining height to the bottom of the browser window. The #3 should be scrollable vertically because it may contain a huge number of "lines".

How this layout can be build using Bootstrap 4 pre-defined CSS styles? Is it possible?

Here is a ... kind of ... try:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 bg-red vh-100">
            #1 Some content on the left side<br>
            should be full height
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 bg-cyan">
            <h1>#2 Some content L1</h1>
            <h1>Some content L2</h1>
            <h1>Some content L3</h1>
            <h1>Some content L4</h1>
            <div class="container-fluid h-100">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div class="col-4 bg-blue overflow-auto">
                        #3 should fill remaining vertical space<br>
                        overflow-Y scroll is needed<br>
                        extra ROW 1<br>
                        extra ROW 2<br>
                        extra ROW 3<br>
                        extra ROW 4<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <div class="bg-green">#4 content</div>
                        <div class="bg-darkgreen">#5 footer line 1 at the bottom of page</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice is very welcome!

Comment: what is the desired height of #2 and #4.. they don't ever have scrollable content?

Comment: #2 needs no scroll, contains some detail info, sometimes more sometimes less. #4 is a panel which also contains a very few info - actually needs no scroll there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex-grow and max-height (`mh-100`). The make the scrolling div (#3) `position-absolute`...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row min-vh-100 mh-100">
        <div class="col-4 bg-red bg-danger"> #1 Some content on the left side<br> should be full height </div>
        <div class="col-8 bg-info d-flex flex-column mh-100">
            <h1>#2 Some content L1</h1>
            <h1>Some content L2</h1>
            <h1>Some content L3</h1>
            <h1>Some content L4</h1>
            <div class="row flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 overflow-hidden">
                <div class="col-4 bg-primary overflow-auto">
                    <div class="position-absolute">
                    #3 should fill remaining vertical space<br> overflow-Y scroll is needed<br>
                    extra ROW 1<br> extra ROW 2<br> extra ROW 3<br> extra ROW 4<br> extra ROW 4<br> extra ROW 4<br>
                     extra ROW 4<br> extra ROW 4<br> extra ROW 4<br> extra ROW 4<br>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column px-0">
                    <div class="bg-success flex-grow-1">#4 content</div>
                    <div class="bg-dark">#5 footer line 1 at the bottom of page</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/DUIcgBdd6Y

Comment: Man! You are a life savior! :) Thanks a lot!